# Optimizing SQL JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database table 'friends' and 'published_post'

```
`friends` --- contains 650K rows 
--------------------------------------------------------
| fb_id_user(bigint)  |   fb_id_friend(bigint) | fb_username(text) |
---------------------------------------------------------


`published_post` ----- contains 6K rows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id(primary_key)(int)  |   fb_id(bigint) | post(text) |  post_date(DATE_TIME) |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

suppose a user has facebook id '12345'. I want to get all the post(`form published_post table`) given by his friends(`from friends table where fb_id_user = '12345'`) in descending order of 'post_time'. 
Any suggestion how this query can be done efficiently would be very helpful.

Comment: The code uses backquotes so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    pp.*
FROM published_post pp
LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.fb_id_user = pp.fb_id
WHERE pp.fb_id_friend = '12345'
ORDER BY f.post_date DESC
```